# Opencv::normalize is too slowly,what should i do?

Tags: c++, opencv

`cv::Mat fixFreImg = averMat.clone(); //fixFreImg.row=3000 fixFreImg.cols=3000 cv::normalize(fixFreImg, fixFreImg, 0, 255, cv::NORM_MINMAX, CV_8U);`
This code took 283ms

The environment I use is C++, MSVC2017, Opencv4.1.3
I hope to reduce the time of this code. I don't have a GPU and can't use CV_CUDA. Do you have any opinions?
=====================news=======================

```
// 创建输出图像
    cv::Mat normalizedImg(fixFreImg.size(), CV_8U);
    // 计算归一化参数
    double minVal, maxVal;
    cv::minMaxLoc(fixFreImg, &minVal, &maxVal);
    double alpha = 255.0 / (maxVal - minVal);
    double beta = -minVal * alpha;


    // 使用OpenMP并行化归一化操作
```

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(threadNum)

```
    for (int i = 0; i < fixFreImg.rows; i++)
    {
        uchar* ptr = normalizedImg.ptr<uchar>(i);
        float* fptr = fixFreImg.ptr<float>(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < fixFreImg.cols; j++)
        {
            ptr[j] = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(alpha * fptr[j] + beta);
        }
    }
```

This code took 156ms！！！

I used openmp to accelerate normalization and there was a significant increase in speed. But perhaps further acceleration is needed, such as block computing.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you don't have CUDA, and it is slow, there are a few options:

If you have an Intel CPU, you can use the Intel-based parallel processing library TBB to speed it up.

If you don't have a supported system or are running on a single core, you may also resize the image and then perform normalization at a lower resolution. If needed, you can iteratively increase the resolution.

If you don't need high precision, you can also convert CV_8U into a 4-bit representation to speed it up.

In the worst-case scenario, you can also use an Intel Neural Computing chip to offload these computations.

Overall, there are many possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will try the TBB acceleration plan again, and I cannot lose my accuracy. I am wondering if it would be faster to split the image into multiple small images for normalization?

Comment: A smaller patch will work locally but might end up having poor global behavior as part of the image has lower contrast and part is higher. For high contrast area it works. For low contrast area,  It may not be a very good idea